# Uploading image to amazon s3 using multer-s3 nodejs

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

I am trying to upload an image to amazon s3 using `multer-s3`, but I am getting this error:

> TypeError: Expected opts.s3 to be object
>   node_modules/multer-s3/index.js:69:20

This is my server code:

```
var upload = multer({
    storage: s3({
        dirname: '/',
        bucket: 'bucket',
        secretAccessKey: 'key',
        accessKeyId: 'key',
        region: 'us-west-2',
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.originalname); 
        }
    })
});

app.post('/upload', upload.array('file'), function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("Uploaded!");
});
```

Why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

**[Update Mar 2022]** It works perfectly fine till-date and now also shows the uploaded file public URL as well.

**Complete** and working [Node Cheat | Upload to s3 using multer-s3](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/aws/express_multer_s3) available.

Code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    aws = require('aws-sdk'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    multer = require('multer'),
    multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    region: 'us-east-1'
});

var app = express(),
    s3 = new aws.S3();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        acl: 'public-read',
        bucket: 'bucket-name',
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            console.log(file);
            cb(null, file.originalname); //use Date.now() for unique file keys
        }
    })
});

//open in browser to see upload form
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');//index.html is inside node-cheat
});

//use by upload form
app.post('/upload', upload.array('upl', 25), function (req, res, next) {
    res.send({
        message: "Uploaded!",
        urls: req.files.map(function(file) {
            return {url: file.location, name: file.key, type: file.mimetype, size: file.size};
        })
    });
});
  
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

*For complete repo*:

Clone node-cheat [express_multer_s3](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/aws/express_multer_s3), run `node app` followed by `npm install express body-parser aws-sdk multer multer-s3`.

Happy Helping!

Comment: Why aren't there a million likes for this answer? This helped me. Thanks. You may want to update :  `aws.config.update({
 signatureVersion: 'v4',` as I was getting an error and doing this solved it.

Comment: Really helpful.

Comment: for me the same line of codes shows this error `"error":{"errno":-4058,"syscall":"open","code":"ENOENT","path":"undefined/undefined"}`

Comment: How we can get the s3 url where we upload the file.

Comment: I tried this code and i got a error like "Error: Unexpected end of multipart data" i dont know why i was searching for solution for couple of days please help me

Comment: Thanks. It works to download file, but when I try to use thi link, it show access denied. How to handle this?

Comment: @Angelzzz pass `acl: 'public-read'` above `bucket: 'bucket-name'` to get desired results.

Comment: It should be in res.files.location @PulkitAggarwal

Comment: 2022 update : This solution does not work anymore

Comment: March 2022 update: It works perfectly fine, just tested it myself. @muragekibicho how can I help you?

Comment: No offence, it does not work - that's why I said it does not work. It may work on your device because of the library versions you are using. @ZeeshanHassanMemon You can help me by letting people know this solution does not work in 2022

Comment: At least tell me the issue so that I can understand what are you facing actually :) or visit the link: https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/aws/express_multer_s3 to know the proper package versions.

Answer (score 21):

@V31 has answered very well still I want to add my 2 cents.

I believe in keeping one responsibility into one file, for better code organization and debugging purpose.

I have created a file for uploading `upload.js`.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

const s3Config = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_IAM_USER_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_IAM_USER_SECRET,
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME
  });

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        cb(null, true)
    } else {
        cb(null, false)
    }
}

// this is just to test locally if multer is working fine.
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, res, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'src/api/media/profiles')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname)
    }
})

const multerS3Config = multerS3({
    s3: s3Config,
    bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
        console.log(file)
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname)
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3Config,
    fileFilter: fileFilter,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5 // we are allowing only 5 MB files
    }
})

exports.profileImage = upload;
```

Which is imported inside my routes `routes.js`

```
const express = require('express');

const ProfileController = require('../profile/controller');
const { profileImage } = require('../utils/upload.js'); 

 const routes = (app) => {
    const apiRoutes = express.Router();

    apiRoutes.use('/profile', profileRoutes);
    profileRoutes.post('/',profileImage.single('profileImage'), ProfileController.saveProfile);

    app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

 }

module.exports = routes
```

Postman screen shot for post body

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the details of the request and body that has to be called from Angular front end or from postman client?

Comment: @Satyam Please check attachment screenshot for post body in Postman

Comment: next edit may be :) @Anjum.... has answered very well still I want to add my 2 cents.

Answer (score 10):

I just want to add my cents,

There are many comments in all answers like **how to get public URL after uploading** and **S3 response object** and lets see implementation and cases,

```js
// INITIALIZE NPMS
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
multer = require('multer'),
multerS3 = require('multer-s3'),
path = require('path');

// CONFIGURATION OF S3
AWS.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: '***********************************',
    accessKeyId: '****************',
    region: 'us-east-1'
});

// CREATE OBJECT FOR S3
const S3 = new AWS.S3();
```

```js
// CREATE MULTER FUNCTION FOR UPLOAD
var upload = multer({
    // CREATE MULTER-S3 FUNCTION FOR STORAGE
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: S3,
        acl: 'public-read',
        // bucket - WE CAN PASS SUB FOLDER NAME ALSO LIKE 'bucket-name/sub-folder1'
        bucket: 'bucket-name',
        // META DATA FOR PUTTING FIELD NAME
        metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
        },
        // SET / MODIFY ORIGINAL FILE NAME
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.originalname); //set unique file name if you wise using Date.toISOString()
            // EXAMPLE 1
            // cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
            // EXAMPLE 2
            // cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname);

        }
    }),
    // SET DEFAULT FILE SIZE UPLOAD LIMIT
    limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 50 }, // 50MB
    // FILTER OPTIONS LIKE VALIDATING FILE EXTENSION
    fileFilter: function(req, file, cb) {
        const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png/;
        const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
        const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
        if (mimetype && extname) {
            return cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb("Error: Allow images only of extensions jpeg|jpg|png !");
        }
    }
});
```

There are three cases, if we want to **retrieve files `res` object from S3 after upload**:

**Case 1:** When we are using **`.single(fieldname)`** method it will return file object in **`req.file`**

```js
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Uploaded!');
    res.send(req.file);
});
```

**Case 2:** When we are using **`.array(fieldname[, maxCount])`** method it will return file object in **`req.files`**

```js
app.post('/upload', upload.array('file', 1), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Uploaded!');
    res.send(req.files);
});
```

**Case 3:** When we are using **`.fields(fields)`** method it will return file object in **`req.files`**

```js
app.post('/upload', upload.fields([
  { name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 },
  { name: 'gallery', maxCount: 8 }
]), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Uploaded!');
    res.send(req.files);
});
```

Comment: The file URL will be in req.file.location

Answer (score 6):

`s3` needs to be an object to be passed. According to the docs, the object needs to be like this:

```
var upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'some-bucket',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString())
    }
  })
})
```

[MulterS3 Docs](https://github.com/badunk/multer-s3)

Comment: Where to provide the accesskeyId for above

Comment: @mBlaze: you need to create a s3 object using var s3 = new aws.S3({ /* ... */ }) using the aws sdk. you can find more info using the link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-json-file.html

Comment: @mBlaze: Just wondering if you were able to resolve your issue. If yes then please mark the answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

/*** Using Multer To Upload Image image is uploading */

```
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./public/uploads");
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

/** AWS catalog */

aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
  region: "us-east-1"
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();
const awsStorage = multerS3({
  s3: s3,
  bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
  key: function(req, file, cb) {
    console.log(file);
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: awsStorage(),
  /** in above line if you are using local storage in ./public/uploads folder than use
   ******* storage: fileStorage,
   * if you are using aws s3 bucket storage than use
   ******* storage: awsStorage(),
   */
  limits: { fileSize: 5000000 },
  fileFilter: function(req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  }
});
app.post("/user-profile-image", upload.single("profile"), (req, res, err) => {
  try {
    res.send(req.file);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(400);
  }
});

const checkFileType = (file, cb) => {
  const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if (mimetype && extname) {
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb("Error: Images Only!");
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Please edit your answer to explain how your code solves the problem OP is facing.

Answer (score 2):

```
    //here is the function for upload the images on aws bucket using multer
    
    const path = require('path');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const aws = require('aws-sdk');
    const multer = require('multer');
    const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
    
    
    aws.config.update({
        secretAccessKey: '**************************',
        accessKeyId: '********************',
        region: '**********************'
    });
    
    s3 = new aws.S3();
    
    
    const storage = multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'bucket-name',
        key: function(req, file, cb) {
            console.log(file);
            cb(null, file.originalname);
        }
    })
    
    //export the created function
    exports.uploadVideo = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file_name');
    
 //================================================================================   
    
    //import uploadVideo function whenever you need to upload the file on aws s3 bucket
    const { uploadVideo } = require('../../services/upload');
    
    exports.videoUpload = (req, res) => {
        uploadVideo(req, res, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.json({ status: 401, msg: err.message });
            } else {
                const image = getImagePath(req.file.filename);
                res.json({ status: 200, msg: 'Image uploaded sucess.', data: image });
            }
        });
    }
    //================================================================================
    
    //here is route file
    router.post('/video-upload',uploadController.videoUpload);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was passing S3 to mutler in caps, like

```
S3: {object}
```

Changing it to small s3 works for me:-

```
s3: {object}
```

Answer (score 0):

WE can Upload IMAGE/ CSV/ EXCEL files to AWS s3 using multer-s3.

Im using **.single(fieldname)** method for uploading single file.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

const s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    region: process.env.REGION,
});

 const upload = multer({
   storage: multerS3({
     s3: s3,
     bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET,
     metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
       cb(null, {fieldName: 'Meta_Data'});
     },
     key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname);
     },
     limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5 //  allowed only 5 MB files
    }
   })
 }).single('file');
 
exports.uploadfile = async(req,res,next)=>{
   try{ 
         upload(req,res, function(err){
             if(err){
                 console.log(err);
             }
             console.log(req.file.location);    
   })
})
}catch (err){
   res.status(400).json({
       status : 'fail', 
       message : err.message
   });
}
}
```

In Routes file

```
router.route('/')
      .post(imageController.uploadfile);
```