# upload image to s3 from node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to s3 but it not happening what I expected.
I create a `file-helper.js` in middleware, that is looks like below

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

aws.config.update({
        accessKeyID:'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',    
        SecretAccessKey:'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        region:'ap-south-1'
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(new Error('Invalid file type, only JPEG and PNG is allowed!'), false);
    }
  }

const upload = multer({
    fileFilter,
    storage: multerS3({
      s3,
      bucket: 'demo.moveies.com',
      acl: 'public-read',
      metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
      },
      key: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now().toString())
      }
    })
  })

  module.exports = upload;
```

and my controller file like below

```
const upload = require('../middleware/file-helper');
const imageUpload = upload.single('image');
exports.fileUpload = async(req,res)=>{
    imageUpload(req, res, function(err, some) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(422).send({errors: [{title: 'Image Upload Error', detail: err.message}] });
        }
        return res.json({'imageUrl': req.file.location});
      });
}
```

when hit the API end point it is giving error

> {
>      "errors": [
>         {
>              "title": "Image Upload Error",
>              "detail": "Missing credentials in config"
>          }
>      ]
>   }

I'm not able to figure out where I went in wrong in my code. can one help me in this situation

Comment: Troubleshoot -- Are your Config for S3 correct ? specifically the region ?

Comment: my s3 bucket region is `Asia Pacific(mumbai)` so I mentioned as `ap-south-1` .. and remaining  `accessKeyID` and `SecretAccessKey` same as s3 bucket

Comment: Be sure about that. you can find your region through the amazon s3 url.

Comment: whatever key I have , I directly configure in `aws.config.update()` please check my question

Comment: @Subhajit even I checked from official documentaion https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: I believe then your code should run..try this link and see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494050/uploading-image-to-amazon-s3-using-multer-s3-nodejs

Comment: I tried still it is not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typos in your config details. It should be `accessKeyId` not `accessKeyID` and `secretAccessKey` and not `SecretAccessKey`.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the wrong key `SecretAccessKey` and `accessKeyID`, try changing it to `secretAccessKey` and `accessKeyId`.

```
aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId:'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',    
    secretAccessKey:'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    region:'ap-south-1'
});
```