# Can I store textarea containing images in mongo db?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, post

I am creating a personal blog using node js and mongo db and implementing the function of writing posts.

I thought that the title and description of the post could be saved in the mongo db in String format, but I am curious about how to save the elements such as the image of the textarea and the font size.

I used tinyMCE as a text editor to write the content and the code is as follows.

```
<form action="/articles" method = "POST">

            <h4>title</h4>
            <input required type="text" name = "title" / class='form-control'><br>
           
            <h4>description</h4>
            <textarea  name="description" class = 'form-control'></textarea><br>
            <h4>contents</h4>
            <textarea id="mytextarea" name="contents" rows = '10'></textarea>
            <a href="/" class ="btn btn-secondary">취소</a><button type = "submit" class="btn btn-primary">저장</button>
        </form>
```

And an example of a post is as follows.

[image]

I am wondering how can I save the contents of a textarea containing a picture in a db.

Comment: Usually, you shouldn't save an image in MongoDB, saving it in file storage of the server and saving the path in MongoDB.

Comment: I guess the challenge is to extract image from text area. If you do that rest will be easy. If it is an URL of an image you can use a regex to obtain the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796914/store-images-in-a-mongodb-database).

However, in terms of scalability I do not recommend uploading pictures to mongoDB. It will take way too much space. What I would do is the following:

1. Create a bucket on AWS s3 or something similar.
2. Connect your nodes.js server to the newly created bucket using multer in combination with the aws-sdk. ([good example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494050/uploading-image-to-amazon-s3-using-multer-s3-nodejs) )
3. Once uploaded the bucket will create a link to the image.
4. Save the image link on mongoDB.

This way you only store the link, which makes the project a lot more scalable.

Comment: Thank you so much for being kind and informed. I don't know if I can do it because I have little knowledge about the web, but I'll try it.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions, I probably will be able to help a bit :)