# How to upload image to external folder using NodeJS multer

Tags: node.js, multer

I am having trouble with the upload destination in nodejs using multer package.
The image are uploading in the folder within nodejs. Bt i want to store that at a different Path outside the project root folder.
Here is the below code

```
const imageURL = "http://localhost/demoAdmin/images/"; 

    const imageStorage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: imageURL, // Destination to store image
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(
          null,
          file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
        );
      },
    });

    const imageUpload = multer({
      storage: imageStorage,
      limits: {
        fileSize: 1000000, // 1000000 Bytes = 1 MB
      },
      fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(png|jpg)$/)) {
          // upload only png and jpg format
          return cb(new Error("Only images allowed"));
        }
        cb(undefined, true);
      },
    }).single("image");

    imageUpload(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        if (err.message) {
          return res.status(500).json({
            success: 0,
            msg: err.message,
          });
        }
        console.log()
        return res.status(500).json({
          success: 0,
          msg: "Only images allowed",
        });
      }
      res.status(200).json({
        success: 1,
        msg: req.file,
      });
    });
```

Any help from your side will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `imageUrl` variable is that it does not point to an absolute path on your server/host.

You need to use the absolute path to the directory of the host/server you want to store images inside.

For example:

```js
const imageURL = "/usr/tmp/demoAdmin/images/";
```

Also, destination takes a function:

```js
destination: (req, file, callback) =>
      callback(null, imageUrl);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to store the image on a url ?

Comment: are you trying to make a URL available after the upload is successful?

Comment: [Can you answer this question? Plz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68408576/how-to-pass-an-id-to-a-url-in-ng2-upload-in-ionic-angular)

Answer (score 0):

Your ImageURL path/value is incorrect

Try this,

```
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
   cb(null, path.join(__dirname + '../../../some/folder/outside/project'))
 }
```

Or you could specify an absolute path of the folder you want the file to be uploaded to. ex: imageURL = "c:\name\myfolder"

To have your image uploaded, hosted in  URL try [Cloudinary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-storage-cloudinary)  [This article is helpful.](https://medium.com/@joeokpus/uploading-images-to-cloudinary-using-multer-and-expressjs-f0b9a4e14c54)

For s3, you could use [Multer-S3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3). [This post helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494050/uploading-image-to-amazon-s3-using-multer-s3-nodejs)

Comment: Is there any way to store the image on a url ?

Comment: You could upload them to aws s3 bucket with appropriate policies for it to be viewable. Or Cloudinary (Updated links in my answer).

Comment: [Can you answer this question? Plz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68408576/how-to-pass-an-id-to-a-url-in-ng2-upload-in-ionic-angular)