# how to pass an id to a URL in ng2 upload in ionic angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, file-upload, routes

I want to pass userID as a parameter in URL in the ng2Upload package.
Below is my TS CODE:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { FileUploader, FileSelectDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload/'; 
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

var uri = 'http://localhost:4000/prescription/upload/';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-prescribtion',
  templateUrl: './prescribtion.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prescribtion.page.scss'],
})
export class PrescribtionPage implements OnInit {
  image;
  imageData;
  userid: any;
  id: string;
  attachmentList: any = [];
  constructor(private storage: Storage) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.storage.get('userid').then((userid) => {
      this.userid = userid;
      uri = uri + userid;
      console.log(uri);
    });
  }

  public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({
    url: uri
  });
}
```

I want to append the userId variable to the url.
Bt it is giving error as Property 'userid' is used before its initialization.

Comment: can you post the error from the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UserId was never initialized, it was only declared. and I don't how the uri was also gonna work, so made a few changes.

```
export class PrescribtionPage implements OnInit {
  image;
  imageData;
  userid: any = null;
  id: string;
  attachmentList: any = [];
  constructor(private storage: Storage) {}
  public uploader: FileUploader;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.storage.get('userid').then((userid) => {
      this.userid = userid;
      var uri: string = "https://whatever.uri.com";
      uri = uri + userid;
      console.log(uri);
      this.uploader = new FileUploader({ url: uri });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: i passed the userid throught  activated route and then i appended it with the URI. Thanks for the help